# In ms outlook inbox not receiving emails to inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

In ms outlook inbox not receiving emails to inbox. It's going to junk folder. How to stop this process.How to configure junk mail to inbox...

Comment: Is the e-mail junk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the mails or certain went into junk ?

If certain emails or valid emails , do visit this > [link](http://helpspot.business.uconn.edu/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=178) <

And if all went into junk , visit this > [link](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/4079) <

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference links, as the answer can become invalid if the linked pages change or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: Web Archived: [How to Prevent Emails from Going to the Junk Email Folder](http://web.archive.org/web/20141112221759/http://helpspot.business.uconn.edu/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=178), [Why is valid email going into my Junk E-mail folder?](http://web.archive.org/web/20141112221808/http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/4079)